# How to call waypoints.js for a div that is dynamically added to the page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

The page contains a small form for the user to fill out - their city, state and zip code. Upon submitting it, the page generates a table of locations. It can be a lengthy table, so I'm trying to use waypoints.js to keep the header div I created (separate from the table), fixed once it reaches the top of the viewport. I'm having troubles getting the plugin to work though since the table is created dynamically.

Comment: i've used `waypoints.js` and had the same problem. My solution was to trigger the `.waypoint()` on that element **after** it was created. Since you didn't post any code, i only can assume this could work.

Comment: How do you trigger it after? By using `$.waypoints('refresh')` ?

Comment: Last comment was @supersize by the way. I think the answer to this question might include calling `$.waypoints('refresh')` in the callback to whatever function adds the new waypoint. But I'm just guessing here.